# What is "open mode" and why is it in Vi but not in Vim?

Tags: command-line, ex-mode, original-vi

From the Vim documentation:

```
1. Simulated command                    *simulated-command*

This command is in Vi, but Vim only simulates it:

                                               *:o* *:op* *:open*
:[range]o[pen]          Works like |:visual|: end Ex mode.
                        {Vi: start editing in open mode}

:[range]o[pen] /pattern/    As above, additionally move the cursor to the
                            column where "pattern" matches in the cursor
                            line.

Vim does not support open mode, since it's not really useful.  For those
situations where ":open" would start open mode Vim will leave Ex mode, which
allows executing the same commands, but updates the whole screen instead of
only one line.
```

This does bother not mention what "open mode" is and I have became interested in it.

Is it another editing mode like `-- REPLACE --` and `-- VISUAL --`?

Can you explain what `open mode` is and tell me why it is useless and got scrapped from Vim?